# Is this the expected result with method synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

So I have this method:

```
public static synchronized int getFilesTaken() {
        int filesTaken = (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * filesLeft / threadsLeft);
        filesLeft -= filesTaken;
        threadsLeft--;
        fileIndex += filesTaken;
        return filesTaken;
    }
```

`filesLeft`, `threadsLeft`, and `fileIndex` are all global variables, used to iterate through a global `File[]`

Then I have this method which is called when a thread is run:

```
public static void parseFiles() {
        int filesTaken = (int) Math.ceil(filesLeft / threadsLeft);
        long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int fileIndexTemp = fileIndex;
        int filesTaken = getFilesTaken();
        System.out.println(fileIndexTemp);
        //rest of the implementation unimportant
}
```

I thought synchronization would make it so that only one thread can access and alter the global variables at a time. However, the print line prints the same numbers across every thread. If I have 1000 filesLeft, and 4 threadsLeft, `fileIndexTemp`, which starts as 0 at the beginning of the program, almost always prints out 0, sometimes printing out 250, 500, or 750, instead of it printing out 0, 250, 500, and 750.

Did I synchronize correctly, and if not, how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A synchronized method will put a lock on `this` when it enters so another thread won't go into the same method. For a static method there is no `this`, so the lock is places on the `Class` instance. So by making `getFilesTaken` all you prevented is that only one thread can enter into `getFilesTaken`, and nothing more. If many threads call `getFiltesTaken`, then will all proceed concurrently, but they will call `getFilesTaken` one by one.

If you need a code block executed by only one thread, you have to synchronize that block using an object common to all threads. If your threads are instances of the same class, you can move that block to a synchronized method. Or, you can use a common object to synchronize on:

```
Object lock=new Object();
...
public static void parseFiles() {
   synchronized(lock) {
     // Critical section
   }
}
```

Above, only one thread will be able to lock `lock` object at any given time.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that I follow the second part. I never create any objects of the class, everything operates on static variables and constants. My goal is to have threads call `getFilesTaken` concurrently, so when each one accesses it, it accesses the updated static variables.

Every thread will eventually need to call `getFilesTaken`, and there is no object common to all Threads.

Comment: I tried what you wrote but I still get the same incorrect output from time to time.

Comment: You are sharing all the global variables among the threads. Whenever you read or write those variables, you have to be in a synchronized block. Synchronizing one method will not work. You have to synchronize all read/writes.

Comment: Thank you that clears things up. However, I'm trying to implement multithreading for the assignment and so far the structure is this: Each method calls `run` which calls `parseFiles` which first calls `getFilesTaken`, then does a bunch of other operations and object creation. Synchronizing `parseFiles` basically undoes the multithreading though, correct? Because each thread now is running one after another, the time I checked is also slower. I think I'll be able to fix it by moving around some operations to other parts of the code, but is there another way to fix it?

Comment: You have to identify the critical sections (sections that access shared data) and synchronize only those. Yes, synchronizing `parseFiles` in your case will defeat the purpose.